# How to convert a list with to wildcards into a list of lists using python?

Tags: python-3.x

I obtained a list of all files in a folder using glob:

```
lista = glob.glob("*.h5")
```

The list basically contains files with names like:

```
   abc_000000000_000.h5
   abc_000000000_001.h5
   abc_000000000_002.h5
   ......
   abc_000000000_011.h5
   ......
   abc_000000001_000.h5
   abc_000000001_001.h5
   abc_000000001_002.h5
   ....
   abc_000000026_000.h5
   abc_000000026_001.h5
   ....
   abc_000000027_000.h5
   ....
   abc_000000027_011.h5
```

which has a format abc_0*_0*.h5. How do I reshape this into a list of lists? The inner list would be ['abc_000000027_0*.h5'] and the outer list would be the sequence of the 'abc_000000*' i.e first wildcard.

One way to create an input would be:

```
 lista=[]
 for i in range(115):
     for j in range(14):
         item="abc_%0.9d_%0.3d"%(i,j)
         lista.append(item)
```

My attempt: my solution is not nice and ugly.

```
     listb = glob.glob("*_011.h5")
     then for each item in listb split and glob again, for example
     listc = glob.glob("abc_000000027*.h5")
```

Comment: The break in each sub list is based on what? Better example == better answer...

Comment: The break is based on the two wildcards. Il'' add it to the question

Comment: Do you mean that your files are of the format `abc_xxxxxxxx_yyy.h5` and you want a dict with `abc_xxxxxxxx` as the key with the value being a list containing the full file names that match the pattern `abc_xxxxxxxx_*.h5`? Please [edit] your question to provide sample input (file names) and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
ls -1
abc_00000001_1.h5
abc_00000001_2.h5
abc_00000001_3.h5
abc_00000002_1.h5
abc_00000002_2.h5
abc_00000002_3.h5
abc_00000003_1.h5
abc_00000003_2.h5
abc_00000003_3.h5
```

You can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [natural sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort) to achieve this:

```
from pathlib import Path 
from itertools import groupby
import re 

p=Path('/tmp/t2')

def _k(s):
    s=str(s)
    try:
        return tuple(map(int, re.search(r'_(\d+)_(\d*)', s).groups()))
    except ValueError:
        return (0,0)
    
def k1(s):
    return _k(s)

def k2(s):
    return _k(s)[0]

result=[]   
files=sorted(p.glob('abc_000000*.h5'), key=k1)
for k,g in groupby(files, key=k2):
    result.append(list(map(str, g)))
```

Which could be simplified to:

```
def _k(p):
    try:
        return tuple(map(int, p.stem.split('_')[-2:]))
    except ValueError:
        return (0,0)
    
files=sorted(p.glob('abc_000000*_*.h5'), key=lambda e: _k(e))
result=[list(map(str, g)) for k,g in groupby(files, key=lambda e: _k(e)[0])]
```

Result (in either case):

```
>>> result
[['/tmp/t2/abc_00000001_1.h5', '/tmp/t2/abc_00000001_2.h5', '/tmp/t2/abc_00000001_3.h5'], ['/tmp/t2/abc_00000002_1.h5', '/tmp/t2/abc_00000002_2.h5', '/tmp/t2/abc_00000002_3.h5'], ['/tmp/t2/abc_00000003_1.h5', '/tmp/t2/abc_00000003_2.h5', '/tmp/t2/abc_00000003_3.h5']]
```

Which easily could be a dict:

```
>>> {k:list(map(str, g)) for k,g in groupby(files, key=k2)}
{1: ['/tmp/t2/abc_00000001_1.h5', '/tmp/t2/abc_00000001_2.h5', '/tmp/t2/abc_00000001_3.h5'], 
 2: ['/tmp/t2/abc_00000002_1.h5', '/tmp/t2/abc_00000002_2.h5', '/tmp/t2/abc_00000002_3.h5'], 
 3: ['/tmp/t2/abc_00000003_1.h5', '/tmp/t2/abc_00000003_2.h5', '/tmp/t2/abc_00000003_3.h5']}
```